I am using search filters brand_name,body_types and year(start or end),what I want If I am searching brand with st year, if not same so don't show,
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
                    $where_clause = " WHERE 1=1";

                    if (!empty($_GET['brand_name']) && $_GET['brand_name'] != 'Choose Brand Name...') {
                        $brand_id = $_GET['brand_name'];
                        $where_clause .= " AND brand_id = ?";
                        $params[] = $brand_id;
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($_GET['body_types']) && $_GET['body_types'] != 'Choose Body Type...') {

                    $body_type = $_GET['body_types'];
                    $where_clause .= " AND body_type = ?";
                    $params[] = $body_type;
                }

                if (!empty($_GET['mfg_start']) && !empty($_GET['mfg_end']) && $_GET['mfg_start'] != 'start_year' && $_GET['mfg_end'] != 'end_year') { {
                        if (!empty($_GET['brand_name']) && $_GET['brand_name'] != 'Choose Brand Name...') {
                            $start_year = $_GET['mfg_start'];
                            $end_year = $_GET['mfg_end'];
                            $where_clause .= " AND mfg_year BETWEEN ? AND ?";
                            $params[] = $start_year;
                            $params[] = $end_year;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $sql .= $where_clause;

I want accurate correction If I search brand name with start year,if not present so don't show the data,what problem happens,suppose I have mahindra brand name in my table,so If i search mahindra with particular year so all the mahindra data shown me, I want whatever I input only be particular data show me if the year is not present so don't show me the data.

Really hard to understand your question. Are you saying, it does not work when you search with only a start year or an end year set (not both)? Your if condition there is checking if both are set (and do not have the placeholder value), otherwise you are not adding any condition for the year to your where clause to begin with.

And AND mfg_year BETWEEN ? AND ? can also hardly work, if you have only a value for one of them. You would either need to use a "default" for the one that is missing, or create a different condition in these cases.

Show sample source data, the search value(s) and the expected output based on the sample data, please. Your description is really quite difficult to understand,  so consider rephrasing that as well. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue.
